# Perl issue: Parameters of HTTP::Cookies set_cookie

Tags: perl, cookies

It's strange I didn't found explanation on every parameters of HTTP::Cookies set_cookie on site [http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Cookies](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP%3a%3aCookies)
For example:

```
$cookie_jar->set_cookie( $version, $key, $val, $path, $domain, $port, $path_spec, $secure, $maxage, $discard, \%rest )
```

Except for $key, $val, what does the rest mean? Saying: $version.
I want to set a authentication cookie for a website and I was told the cookie as "Ticket=UmVhZE9ubHlUb2tlbg== "

```
my $cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new( file => '$ENV{\'HOME\'}/lwp_cookies.dat', autosave => 1);
$cookie_jar->set_cookie(1, "Ticket", "UmVhZE9ubHlUb2tlbg== ", "/path/to/authenticate", "stackoverflow.com", "443");
#authenticating
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->cookie_jar($cookie_jar);
$ua->request(GET $someString);
```

Anyway, the authentication failed and so did the $ua->request. Firstly, I didn't know how to set $version because the doc didn't tell me its meaning. I tried 1 or 0, both failed. The whole authenticate path should be, neglecting the spaces for display restriction:

```
https: / /stackoverflow.com /path/to/authenticate
```

For the lwp_cookies.dat, if the file not exist, could it be created automatically? I add one line "$cookie_jar->save;" and got a message of "lwp_cookies.dat: No such file or directory".

Could anyone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the RFC 2965 spec:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965

http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html

Comment: Your links are very helpful. Thanks. I've known how to set the cookies. But the lwp_cookies.dat not found when I try to use $cookie_jar->save. Anyway, the original question has been answered.